# Rails common filters for controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some common filters that I use for two controllers. The filters are exactly the same however the skip conditions are different in both the controllers.

In u_controller:

```
  before_filter :require_login,:get_notification,:get_credits

  skip_before_filter :require_login , :only =>  [:index,:registration,:login,:oauthlogin,
                                                :forgotpassword,:invite_mail,:newpassword,
                                                :changepassword,:invite,:verify,:terms,:privacy,:about]
  skip_before_filter :get_notification , :only => [:registration,:login,:oauthlogin,
                                                :forgotpassword,:invite_mail,:newpassword,
                                                :changepassword,:invite,:verify]
  skip_before_filter :get_credits , :only => [:registration,:login,:oauthlogin,
                                                :forgotpassword,:invite_mail,:newpassword,
                                                :changepassword,:invite,:verify,:terms,:privacy,:about]
```

In q_controller:

```
before_filter :require_login,:get_notification,:get_credits,:require_auth

   skip_before_filter :get_notification,:get_credits,:require_auth,
                      :only => [:topic_suggest,:upload,:new_question,:qdb,:post_new_question,:evaluate_answer,:image]
   skip_before_filter :require_auth, :only => [:add]
```

What would be the best practice in such a scenario, to solve the following problem:

1. Avoid duplicate declaration of filters in the two controllers
2. Use cleaner code instead of `skip_before_filter`.

Comment: nice question, dont have an answer myself.

Comment: Inherit from specialized controllers, actually your action names are so varied I wonder why a single controller would bear all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've really got two questions here, so I'll answer each separately:

1: In order to avoid before_filter duplication you can extract the common declaration to a module and include it in both controllers:

```
module BeforeFilters
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
       before_filter :filter1, :filter2
    end
  end
end

class UController
  include BeforeFilter
end

class QController
  include BeforeFilter
end
```

2: I think that the reason you have to skip the before_filter in so many actions is just the fact that you have too many of them in a single controller. My advice to you is to separate the actions to two or more controllers, and declare before filters in each controller as needed. This will spare you all the skip_before_filter declarations.

Comment: Is there a way to skip filters defined in the module? Rearranging the controllers would be a huge task right now, but yeah I do plan to move them around in the future.

Comment: you can add `skip_before_filter` in the class_eval block just as I added the before_filter

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the `skip_before_filter`: use `except` in `before_filter`.

**u_controller:**

```
before_filter :require_login, :except => [:index,:registration,:login ....]

before_filter :get_notification, :except => [:registration,:login,:oauthlogin...]

before_filter :get_credits, :except => [:registration,:login,:oauthlogin...]
```

**q_controller:**

```
before_filter :require_login,:get_notification,:get_credits, :except => [:topic_suggest,:upload,:new_question,:qdb,:post_new_question,:evaluate_answer,:image]

before_filter :require_auth, :except => [:add]
```

Avoid duplicate declaration of filters in the two controllers:

You don't need it, since you have another functions to skip them for each controller.
If you need to apply it for each function in each controller, you could do it in before_filter at application_controller.

*Notice*:
If you have more functions to apply them, than functions to skip them, I would recommend using `:only` instead of `:except`.

Comment: just for curiosity i wanted to know hw is `:except` better than `skip_before_filter`?

Comment: One line instead of two... But if we have the `before_filter` common for all our controllers, and declared in base controller, then we'll have to use `skip`, for skipping the functions in every controller...

Comment: `before_filter` with `except` option is like `before_filter + skip_before_filter`